Can't select date with Livewire 3 and Airdatepicker
I cannot select the date field with Livewire 3. I am using Airdatepicker and when I select the date field, I cannot assign it to the $selected_date variable with wire:model from the input field. How can I achieve this situation?
<div class="iyzi-booking-date-select">
    <h4>{{ __('frontend.select_date') }}</h4>
    <div class="iyzi-form-group mt-3">
        <div class="iyzi-datepicker-wrap">
            <input type="text" wire:model="selected_date" wire:click="optionchange" id="iyzi-booking-datepicker" placeholder="{{ __('frontend.select') }}" class="iyzi-booking-datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


Since the value is not typed in the input, the wire:model is not evaluated.
We can use an event of Airdatepicker to fill the component variable via javascript:
<div>

    <div class="iyzi-booking-date-select">

        <h4>{{ __('frontend.select_date') }}</h4>

        <div class="iyzi-form-group mt-3">

            <div class="iyzi-datepicker-wrap" >

                <input type="text"
                       {{--wire:model="selected_date"--}}
                       {{--wire:click="optionchange"--}}
                       id="iyzi-booking-datepicker"
                       placeholder="{{ __('frontend.select') }}"
                       class="iyzi-booking-datepicker"
                >

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <span> {{-- this was set for debugging purposes --}}
        [
        @empty($selected_date)
            {{  var_export($selected_date, return: true) }}
        @else
            {{  $this->selected_date }}
        @endempty
        ]
    </span>

</div>


@script
<script>

    new AirDatepicker('#iyzi-booking-datepicker', {

         // your custom options...

         onSelect ({date}) {

             // simple conversion to locale format or null
             $wire.selected_date = date ? new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() : null;

             // console.log ($wire.selected_date);

             $wire.$refresh();  // this emulates wire:model.blur
         }});

</script>
@endscript

In my example I used the onSelect event to set the component's selected_date property via Javascript.
I also added a <span> in the view to show the updated value coming from the backend and to have the result immediately I also added a $wire.$refresh() in the javascript to emulate a wire:model.blur

Another possible solution is to use Alpine's x-init in the container of the input to initialize the Airdatepicker:
<div class="iyzi-datepicker-wrap"
     x-init="new AirDatepicker('#iyzi-booking-datepicker', {
             onSelect ({date}) {
                $wire.selected_date = date ? new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() : null;
                $wire.$refresh(); // emulates wire:model.blur if needed
    }});"
>
    <input type="text"
           id="iyzi-booking-datepicker"
           placeholder="{{ __('frontend.select') }}"
           class="iyzi-booking-datepicker"
    >

</div>


It still didn't work, I can't transfer the date to selected_date.

I tested my code and it works for me. Have you commented/removed wire:model and wire:click like in my example? Do you initialize the date picker with a @script @endscript block in the component or in a different way? Have you made a test adding the debugging  and the $wire.$refresh()? Have you tried to enable the console.log() that I commented in my code? Do you receive any error in the console of the browser?

I did what you said. I get this error. Uncaught ReferenceError: $wire is not defined

I get the same error if I don't enclose the  section with @script @endscript. You're using Livewire 3, right?

Yes, I am using livewire 3 and I did exactly what you said. I check again and again but the result is the same.

Try replacing every $wire with @this, for example: @this.selected_date = date ? new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() : null;

I can't find this in the documentation either. It didn't work the way you said. Where exactly should I write the javascript codes? Maybe I'm making a mistake there.

// Dispatch an event to any Livewire components listening...  problem solved this way.
Livewire.dispatch('post-created', { selected_date: date ? new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() : null })     #[On('post-created')]     public function handleNewPost($selected_date)     {         $this->selected_date = $selected_date;     }

The javascript code of my solution must be placed at the bottom of  the component as I showed.

I added an additional solution that uses Alpine's x-init to initialize the datepicker instead of using external scripts
